# Class Object is always null

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

This is the method when my app complete the downloading with contact which is coming from server. In for loop I am using `AIContactParsarModal` class and using dictionary I am setting the objects, but *every time object value is null*.

Thanks for the help and any help will be appreciable. Here is my code.

```
- (void)donewithContact {

    self.allPersonDetailsDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithCapacity:1];
    NSMutableArray *allKeysArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *prefix;

    NSString *searchContactString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AdvanceSearch"];
    if ([searchContactString isEqualToString:@"SpecialSearch"]) {
        [self.allPersonDetailsDict removeAllObjects];
    }
    if (getContactArray.count == 0 ){
        [noContactLabel setHidden:NO];
    } else {
        for (AIContactParsarModal *contact in getContactArray) {
            NSLog(@"contact LAST NAMES ARE %@",contact.lastName);
            prefix = [[contact.lastName substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)] uppercaseString];

            if ([allKeysArray containsObject:prefix]) {
                NSMutableArray *conatctsWithPrefix = [_allPersonDetailsDict objectForKey:prefix];
                [conatctsWithPrefix addObject:contact];
            } else {
                [allKeysArray addObject:prefix];
                NSMutableArray *conatctsWithPrefix = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:contact,nil];
                [self.allPersonDetailsDict setObject:conatctsWithPrefix forKey:prefix];
                NSLog(@"conatctsWithPrefix %@",conatctsWithPrefix);
            }
        }
    [noContactLabel setHidden:YES];
    }
    NSLog(@"All Names First characters are:%@", allKeysArray);

    [self.contactTableView reloadData];
    [HUD hide:YES];
}
```

Comment: conatctsWithPrefix is always null

Comment: what is getContactArray?

Comment: may be you are getting null value in contact by which you are getting null in conatctsWithPrefix

Comment: ya that i know but my contact is null i am not understanding why ?

Comment: could you log `getContactArray` ?

Comment: getContactArray is having 153 object which is the type of AIContactParsarModal.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are getting null value in contact by which you are getting null in conatctsWithPrefix

first print values stored in contact.

Comment: contact value is null that i know but why it is so that i dont know

Comment: first try to give a hardcoded value to null then check step by step of contact value i can tell you that reason  but i will you will not learn so first try to solve yourself  then i will help you

Comment: harcode value is coming if i will give some value instead of contact then value is coming